# undefined local variable or method `blog' for

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a CRUD action setup for **Blog**

This is my controller

```
class BlogsController < ApplicationController

  def new
    @blog = Blog.new
  end

  def create
    @blog = Blog.new(blog_params)

    if @blog.save
      redirect_to @blog
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  def show
    @blog = Blog.find(params[:id])
  end

  def edit
  end

  def destroy
  end

  def index
    @blogs = Blog.all.order(created_at: :desc)
  end

  private

    def blog_params
      params.require(:blog).permit(:title, :body, :image)
    end

end
```

My index is working fine, but when I click the "Read Post" link, I get the error: undefined local variable or method `blog'

The code for my show.html.erb is

```
<html>
  <head>

  </head>
  <body>
    <div>
      <h2><%= blog.title %></h2>
      <h5><%= blog.body %></h5>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Does anybody know what's wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refer to instance variables:

```
<h2><%= @blog.title %></h2>
<h5><%= @blog.body %></h5>
```

In your controller, you are setting instance variable `@blog`. Rails will take all defined instance variables in your controller and define them in your view. That's why you need to use instance var.